# How do I convert a generator matrix G to standard form?

Tags: matrices, coding-theory

I'm trying to convert a generator matrix for a (10,4) code to standard form. (mod 2). I've looked for a while how to do this but I can't seem to find it.

Matrix is

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
        0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
        1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Gauss elimination will give a $4\times 10$ matrix of reduced echelon form $(I_4\mid A)$, where $I_4$ is the $4\times 4$ identity matrix. Note that if you need column permutations, then you will get a generator matrix for an equivalent linear code.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) software to obtain the generator matrix  in the standard form [as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7EzD.jpg).